# Reading non-packed repeated field with packed=true proto file

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I just realized that there is an option for a more efficient use of protocol buffers to read/write arrays of primitives. I already have protobuf files without packed=true. My question is what happens when I add this option to my .proto and compile it. Will I be able to read the previously saved protobufs (that are not saved with this option)?

```
repeated int32 samples = 4 [packed=true];
```

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually, it does, in Google-authored implementations 2.3.0 and later.

Comment: @KentonVarda heh, I stand corrected - I based that off my original understanding from when it first came out. In my own library I try to make it as forgiving as possible, but historically I was under the impression that the google implementation tried to be very strict. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 2.3.0 (Jan 2010), the Google-authored implementations of Protobufs (in C++, Java, and Python) can accept data in either format when parsing.  The `packed` setting only tells the implementation which format to use when writing.  See [the changelog](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/CHANGES.txt) (first item under v2.3.0).

Versions 2.1 (when packed fields were introduced) and 2.2 do *not* have this property -- the parsers in these versions only accept `[packed=true]` fields in packed format, and non-`[packed=true]` fields in non-packed format.

Third-party implementations may or may not support this feature.  You'll have to check their docs, or maybe write a test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a 100% certain answer, and you should be able to verify this with a quick test, but if you look at the [wire format specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), you'll find the wire format of packed fields. However, since the tag name and wire type is clearly identifiable, you should always be able to *read* a serialized protobuf, even if something crazy happens and you have multiple packed values *and* multiple unpacked values, all for the same field. They would just all be concatenated. The `packed` options should mainly dictate how a protobuf is *written*.

Do make a test case to be sure, though.

And of course your reader needs to support at least Proto 2.1.0.